# How to get the value of the output of ls/dir command in a Linux shell console?

Tags: shell, store

I need to to this operation automaticaly:

```
$ ls
this_folder
$ cp -rf this_folder/* .
```

For this I need to store in a variable the value of the "ls" so that I do something like this:

```
$ ls
this_folder
$ cp -rf $value_of_the_ls/* .
```

It is possible to do this? Give me some clues.

Best Regards,

Comment: Storing the output of ls in a variable is certainly one option.  However, it is incorrect to say that you "need to" do that.  You could easily pipe the output of ls to a while loop, or do a for loop over a glob, or use find, or xargs, or ...

Comment: Anything wrong with `cp -rf */* .`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set the output of a command into a variable, use [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) like this:

```
$ value_of_the_ls=$(ls)
$ echo "${value_of_the_ls}"
```

Have you thought about what you will do if there are multiple files in the current directory in which case `ls` will return multiple files?